# TryParse Handling in Loop

Tags: c#

I'm using `TryParse` to check if user enters integer or not in a loop and if user enters any character or non integer value user will receive invalid message and loop goes to next iteration.

I want user to re-enter input to same iteration.

```
int[] number = new int[5];
int newSum = 0;
int outValue;
Console.Write("Enter Five Integer Digits: \n");
for (int i = 0; i <= number.Length - 1; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Number {0}: ", i);
    bool Parse = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out outValue);
    if (Parse)
    {
        number[i] = outValue;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You Have Entered InValid Format: ");
    }
    newSum += number[i];
}
Console.WriteLine("Sun of Numbers :{0}", newSum);
```

```
I expected the output to be
Number 2: h
You Have Entered InValid Format:
Number 2: 
But the actual output is 
Number 2: h
You Have Entered InValid Format:
Number 3:
```

Comment: Instead of `for` use `do-while`

Comment: Use a list instead of an array. Leave the `for` or `do` once the list is of  the expected size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rewrite you loop in following way:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= number.Length - 1; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Number {0}: ", i);
    bool Parse = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out outValue);
    if (Parse)
    {
        // if parsing is successfull, then add to array and to sum :)
        number[i] = outValue;
        newSum += number[i];
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You Have Entered InValid Format: ");
        // just decrement iterator to repeat this iteration
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Number {0}: ", i);
                bool Parse = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out outValue);
                if (Parse)
                {
                    number[i] = outValue;
                    newSum += number[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    i--;
                    Console.WriteLine("You Have Entered InValid Format: ");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of changing the value of the index inside a for-next loop (code smell!).
An alternative is:

```
var i=0;
while (i < 5)
{
    Console.Write("Number {0}: ", i);
    bool Parse = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out outValue);
    if (Parse)
    {
        number[i] = outValue;
        newSum += number[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You Have Entered InValid Format: ");
    }
}
```

It would be worth checking for some form of "escape" character as the while loop will not exit until 5 acceptable values are entered.